# How can I access all questions asked by an arbitrary user?

Tags: support, api, questions

Within the web app for courses I organize, I'd like students to be able to provide their Stack Overflow username, so that we can pull in their most recent and unanswered questions. This information is [already publicly available](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=questions&sort=newest), but I'd like to pull it in through an API and list them together, so that students can see what's being asked and answer each other's questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler and more precise if you made users provide their ID number instead (for example, yours is `1637442` on Stack Overflow).

Then you'd merely use [the `/users/{ids}/questions` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-on-users) to get the questions.

If you really must have access by username, then:

1. First do a search using the `inname` parameter of [the `/users` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users).
   It is recommended that you cache these results, since they will change infrequently.
2. Then run the `/users/{ids}/questions` as before.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I somehow wasn't finding this browsing the API docs. A few more notes for those with similar problems: A) You can list up to 100 ids, delimited by semicolons. B) You can further filter questions by unanswered or with no answers, etc. C) There are some good sorting options in the doc links provided.

Comment: Thanks, I would 'upvote', but I don't have that privilege on stackapp yet lol.